# Read variable from python file using java

Tags: java

How can I get the values from python file.

For Example :

```
 $ipaddress_range = [
               "10.0.0.1/21",
               "10.0.0.3/21",
               "10.0.50.1/25",
               "10.3.0.1/25"
];

 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

           if(!line.startsWith("#") && !line.isEmpty() && !line.trim().equals("") && !line.trim().equals("\n")){
               System.out.println(line);
           }
        }
```

Now I would like to read the variable name and its value. correspondingly save it in a Map or any other data structure in java.

Comment: What have you got so far? Do you need help knowing how to read a file? How to find the line you're interested in? How to parse the values? What specific part are you asking about?

Comment: I know how to read a file but i am not able to read the above line as a single line and get the variable name and value as key value pair for a java map.

Comment: If you have some code for reading a file, that would be a good start. Currently you have just posted a problem with no contribution from yourself, so your question is likely to get closed as "too broad"

Comment: updated with some java code

Comment: First `$ipaddress_range = ...` is not a correct Python source. And parsing a language can be a complex operation and the only foolproof way in the general case is to use a dedicated parser. So unless what you call *values from python file* is a very specific format, my advice is not to try to process it directly.

Comment: Sorry.. you are right. It was TrafficScript from brocade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am doing something like this and it serves the purpose.

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String line;

        List<String> exIps = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, List<String>> stingrayIps = new HashMap<>();
        boolean startedExt = false;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {


            if (!line.startsWith("#") && !line.isEmpty() && !line.trim().equals("") && !line.trim().equals("\n")) {
                if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("$ipaddress_range = [")) {
                    startedExt = true;
                } else if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("];")) {
                    startedExt = false;
                }

                if (startedExt && !line.equalsIgnoreCase("$ipaddress_range = [")) {
                    exIps.add(line.replaceAll(",$", "").replaceAll("\"", "").trim());
                }
            }
        }
        if (exIps.size() > 0) {
            stingrayIps.put("stingrayIps", exIps);
        }
```